# GPUImage crop to CGRect and rotate

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

Given a `CGRect`, I want to use GPUImage to crop a video. For example, if the rect is `(0, 0, 50, 50)`, the video would be cropped at `(0,0)` with a length of 50 on each side.

What's throwing me is that `GPUImageCropFilter` doesn't take a rectangle, rather a normalized crop region with values ranging from 0 to 1. My intuition was to to this:

```
let assetSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(videoTrack.naturalSize, videoTrack.preferredTransform)
let cropRect = CGRect(x: frame.minX/assetSize.width,
                y: frame.minY/assetSize.height,
                width: frame.width/assetSize.width,
                height: frame.height/assetSize.height)
```

to calculate the crop region based on the size of the incoming asset. Then:

```
// Filter
let cropFilter = GPUImageCropFilter(cropRegion: cropRect)
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(String.random()).mp4")
let movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: url, size: assetSize)
movieWriter.encodingLiveVideo = false
movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = false

// add targets
movieFile.addTarget(cropFilter)
cropFilter.addTarget(movieWriter)

cropFilter.forceProcessingAtSize(frame.size)
cropFilter.setInputRotation(kGPUImageRotateRight, atIndex: 0)
```

What should the movie writer size be? Shouldn't it be the size of the frame I want to crop with? And should I be using `forceProcessingAtSize` with the size value of my crop frame?

A complete code example would be great; I've been trying for hours and I can't seem to get the section of the video that I want.

FINAL:

```
if let videoTrack = self.asset.tracks.first {
            let movieFile = GPUImageMovie(asset: self.asset)
            let transformedRegion = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(region, videoTrack.preferredTransform)

            // Filters
            let cropFilter = GPUImageCropFilter(cropRegion: transformedRegion)

            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(String.random()).mp4")
            let renderSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(videoTrack.naturalSize, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(transformedRegion.width, transformedRegion.height))

            let movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: url, size: renderSize)
            movieWriter.transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform

            movieWriter.encodingLiveVideo = false
            movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = false

            // add targets
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041231/gpuimage-crop-to-cgrect-and-rotate
            movieFile.addTarget(cropFilter)
            cropFilter.addTarget(movieWriter)

            movieWriter.completionBlock = {
                observer.sendNext(url)
                observer.sendCompleted()
            }

            movieWriter.failureBlock = { _ in
                observer.sendFailed(.VideoCropFailed)
            }

            disposable.addDisposable {
                cropFilter.removeTarget(movieWriter)
                movieWriter.finishRecording()
            }

            movieWriter.startRecording()
            movieFile.startProcessing()
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, the GPUImageCropFilter takes in a rectangle in normalized coordinates. You're on the right track, in that you just need to convert your CGRect in pixels to normalized coordinates by dividing the X components (origin.x and size.width) by the width of the image and the Y components by the height.

You don't need to use `forceProcessingAtSize()`, because the crop will automatically output an image of the appropriate cropped size. The movie writer's size should be matched to this cropped size, which you should know from your original CGRect.

The one complication you introduce is the rotation. If you need to apply a rotation in addition to your crop, you might want to check and make sure that you don't need to swap your X and Y for your crop region. This should be apparent in the output if the two need to be swapped.

There were some bugs with applying rotation at the same time as a crop a while ago, and I can't remember if I fixed all those. If I didn't, you could insert a dummy filter (gamma or brightness set to default values) before or after the crop and apply the rotation at that stage.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right because if I apply `videoTrack.preferredTransform` onto my crop region, then crop and output, the outputted video is rotated but cropped precisely how I want it. Then if I run it through a rotation filter, the rotation works but I get black bars on the side of the video that weren't and shouldn't be there.

Comment: I posted the code that I finally got working. Turns out I didn't have to use a rotate filter at all, I just set the transform of the movie writer to the transform for the video track.

There are two things though, that you might know something about. When I export a movie and open up my documents folder via xcode, two things happen: 1) All my movies that I've cropped have a black bar on the side. 2) When I click to play the movie, quicktime converts the files and the conversion gets rid of the side bars. Any idea what that's about?